# Stop/Restart GLib.Timeout.Add();

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, glib, gtk#

This function starts a timer in GTK#. I want to be able to start and stop this as I please.

```
void StartClock ()
 {
    GLib.Timeout.Add (1000, new GLib.TimeoutHandler (AskPython));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glib timeout doesn't support that but here is a timer class I wrote that mimics Microsoft's timer class.

```
public delegate void TimerElapsedHandler (object sender, TimerElapsedEventArgs args);

public class TimerElapsedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    DateTime signalTime;

    public TimerElapsedEventArgs () {
        signalTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class Timer
{
    private bool _enabled;
    public bool enabled {
        get {
            return _enabled;
        }
        set {
            _enabled = value;
            if (_enabled)
                Start ();
            else
                Stop ();
        }
    }
    protected uint timerId;

    public event TimerElapsedHandler TimerElapsedEvent;
    public uint timerInterval; 
    public bool autoReset;

    public Timer () : this (0) { }

    public Timer (uint timerInterval) {
        _enabled = false;
        this.timerInterval = timerInterval;
        autoReset = true;
        timerId = 0;
    }

    public void Start () {
        _enabled = true;
        timerId = GLib.Timeout.Add (timerInterval, OnTimeout);
    }

    public void Stop () {
        _enabled = false;
        GLib.Source.Remove (timerId);
    }

    protected bool OnTimeout () {
        if (_enabled) {
            if (TimerElapsedEvent != null)
                TimerElapsedEvent (this, new TimerElapsedEventArgs ());
        }
        return _enabled & autoReset;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Timer t = new Timer (1000);
t.TimerElapsedEvent += (sender, args) => {
    Console.WriteLine (args.signalTime.ToString ());
};
t.enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a global variable to disable that could be checked within `AskPython` function and do nothing if it is set.
- Otherwise, which I think is the right way for GLib. `AskPython` should return `false`.

  > The function is called repeatedly until it returns False, at which point the timeout is automatically destroyed and the function will not be called again.

  **Reference:** [glib.timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add)

  Then call `GLib.Timeout.Add` if you want to enable it again.